# Maximum derivative of meaning

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

In mathematics, typically at what level of differential does a nominal derivative lose meaning? I think of the common example of jerk being the derivative of acceleration. But does the derivative of jerk have meaning? Are there other systems where the 5th or 6th derivative has any real-world, or abstract, meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is never -- you are citing *classical physics* examples, where anything beyond the 4th derivative of position wrt time is really hard to give much physical meaning to apart from the brute definition.

For example, in the Taylor series for $sin(x)$, the $f^{(n)}$th derivative is used to calculate the $n$-th term of the approximating equation, so it has "meaning" as the $n$-th refinement of an approximating polynomial. We can even use Taylor's remainder theorem to understand the magnitude of the correction (i.e., numerical significance). Since $sin(x)$ is infinitely differentiable, this applies to any derivative.

Comment: I guess how many curves are there where the derivative doesn't become a line and then a scalar within 4-5 derivatives. Cosine/sine do alternate though.

Comment: We have all asked this question to ourselves but few of us wanted to look dumb enough to ask it lol

Comment: @AlexanderMills any polynomial with degree greater than 7, $\frac1x$...there are countless types of functions that have interesting higher order derivatives.